# AWS EMR Spark is creating files on worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, amazon-emr, datanode

I am using spark on EMR to process data. Basically i read data from AWS S3 and do the transformation and post transformation i am loading/writing data to oracle tables.

Recently we have found that hdfs(/mnt/hdfs) utilization is going too high.

I am not writing any data to hdfs(/mnt/hdfs) however is that spark is creating blocks and writing data into it. We are going all the operations in memory.

Why Spark is still writing data to data node?

Any specific operation writing data to datanode(HDFS)?

Here is the hdfs dirs created.

*15.4G    /mnt/hdfs/current/BP-6706123673-10.xx.xx.xxx-1588026945812/current/finalized/subdir1

129G     /mnt/hdfs/current/BP-6706123673-10.xx.xx.xxx-1588026945812/current/finalized

129G     /mnt/hdfs/current/BP-6706123673-10.xx.xx.xxx-1588026945812/current

129G     /mnt/hdfs/current/BP-6706123673-10.xx.xx.xxx-1588026945812

129G     /mnt/hdfs/current
129G     /mnt/hdfs*

Comment: What is your persistence set to? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Comment: Hi @SašaZejnilović, persistence level is default(MEMORY_ONLY). Is the data shuffle creating these files?

Comment: Look at spark ui for the memory usage. It may happen because of big shuffle.

Comment: Is there any way to cleanup these files?

Comment: @distributed_world did you have any luck with that?

Comment: @EliGolin - These file was created by Spark App logs and i have to delete them manually.

Comment: can you give more details about the solution? What's spark app logs? And why is spark moving Spark app logs to hdfs?